# Decorator that creates classes

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class

```
class Test:
    name = "Test"
```

I want to create a decorator mc_me which after:

```
@mc_me
class Test:
    name = "Test"
```

will provide me with three classes exactly like if I've written:

```
class Test:
    name = "Test"

class TestSuper:
    name = "TestSuper"

class TestExtra:
    name = "TestExtra"
```

So essentially the first tricky part is deep copying a class and the second is assigning three variables on caller's scope. It feels like it should be possible somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import inspect

def mc_me(cls):
    main_locals = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
    for suffix in ['Super', 'Extra']:
        new_name = cls.__name__ + suffix
        main_locals[new_name] = type(new_name, (), {'name': new_name})
    return cls
```

Be careful, **this is not the best way to code**. With great power comes great responsibility. I encourage you to check out all possible drawbacks of the `inspect` approach (Google is your friend).

Comment: Sick and beautiful! :) With the note: "CPython implementation detail: This function relies on Python stack frame support in the interpreter, which isn’t guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python." [inspect.currentframe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe)

Comment: Only works at top-level or class-level, and I'm pretty sure you were supposed to return `cls`.

Comment: Forgot `return cls`, you're right. I can't see the problem with top-level restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Making 3 classes is easy. Assigning the results to 3 variables, though? That violates Python's scope rules.

```
@mc_me
class Test:
    name = "Test"
```

is equivalent to

```
class Test:
    name = "Test"
Test = mc_me(Test)
```

There's no way for the decorator to say that it wants to create some more variables and assign to those too. Even if you somehow managed to get it to work (probably only at module or class scope with `inspect` craziness), Python would have no way to know that references to `TestSuper` or `TestExtra` should refer to the variables created by the decorator when compiling the bytecode.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I was thinking something along the lines of... `(Test, TestSuper, TestExtra) = mc_me(Test)` "Making 3 classes is easy" - With type? Could you deep-copy and monkey patch somehow? (I know it sounds like inheritance). In any case the below should be a straightforward alternative  

`    class Test:
        name = "Test"

    TestSuper = mc_me(Test, "Super")
    TestExtra = mc_me(Test, "Extra")`

Comment: *Python would have no way to know that references to TestSuper or TestExtra should refer to the variables created by the decorator when compiling the bytecode.* Sure? Bytecode won't include the newly created `TestSuper` and `TestExtra` but the instructions to create them. In fact, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out that abandoning the decorator idea and using a regular function that returns a tuple is the closest to achieving the result I want.

```
# Library code
def mc_me(base):
    class Sp(base):
        name = base.name + "Super"

    class Ex(base):
        name = base.name + "Extra"

    return (Sp, Ex)

# Application code
class Test:
    name = "Test"

(TestSuper, TestExtra) = mc_me(Test)
```